# Getting days of the week in a list and then getting it to start over

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, api, loops

Beginner here. I've looked around a lot and found how to get the day of the week in JavaScript and I made a function to to change the number to the day abbreviations.

What I'm stuck on is getting the next day to show up. It all shows up as the day that the query is made so the "+ 1", "+ 2", etc. in the variables don't do anything. Also, I'm having trouble getting the days to reset and start over when a week ends when looking forward in something such as a weather forecast.

I know it's going to require an object of some sort and a loop but everything I've been doing doesn't seem to work.

```js
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDay();

var firstDay = +1;
var secondDay = day + 2;
var thirdDay = day + 3;
var fourthDay = day + 4;
var fifthDay = day + 5;

function processForecastResults(data) {
  if (data.city.name !== undefined) {
    function transformDay() {
      if (day === 0) {
        return "Sun";
      } else if (day === 1) {
        return "Mon";
      } else if (day === 2) {
        return "Tues";
      } else if (day === 3) {
        return "Wed";
      } else if (day === 4) {
        return "Thurs"
      } else if (day === 5) {
        return "Fri";
      } else if (day === 6) {
        return "Sat";
      }
    }

    $("#monthOne").html(transformDay(firstDay));
    $("#monthTwo").html(transformDay(secondDay));
    $("#monthThree").html(transformDay(thirdDay));
    $("#monthFour").html(fourthDay);
    $("#monthFive").html(fifthDay);
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It would seem at first glance that all you need is an incremental integer to keep track of the day you want along with the modulo operator to start the loop over again when the end is reached

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not certain exactly what it is you're trying to achieve, but you can simplify the logic and avoid your problems by using an array to store the day names. You can then increment the day per element that the day names should be shown in while using the modulo operator to make the values start over when the end of the array is reached. Try this:

```js
var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var day = new Date().getDay();

$('.day-name').text(function(i) {
  return dayNames[(day + ++i) % dayNames.length];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="day-name"></div>
<div class="day-name"></div>
<div class="day-name"></div>
<div class="day-name"></div>
<div class="day-name"></div>
<div class="day-name"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great! Basically what I was trying to achieve is what you posted. A five day forecast with it resetting to Sunday after Saturday. This let me delete a bunch of my bad code.